# JSR-354 MonetaryAmountFormat not working two way for other currency symbols than $, € or £

Tags: java, internationalization, currency-formatting, java-money, jsr354

Here is example code that I'm using with [Moneta version 1.1](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/tree/1.1-release):

```
    Locale LANG = Locale.CHINA;  // also tried new Locale("pl", "PL");

    final MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
            AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(LANG)
                    .set(CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
                    .set("pattern", "#,##0.00### ¤")
                    .build()
    );
    final String formatted = format.format(Money.of(new BigDecimal("1234.56"), Monetary.getCurrency(LANG)));

    System.out.println(formatted);

    System.out.println(format.parse(formatted).getNumber());
```

This should work since I'm converting same object back and forth. Unless I got something wrong and converter is not two-way for other currencies than $, € or £.

The last line crashes with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid error index > input.length
at javax.money.format.MonetaryParseException.<init>(MonetaryParseException.java:56)
at org.javamoney.moneta.internal.format.AmountNumberToken.parse(AmountNumberToken.java:140)
at org.javamoney.moneta.internal.format.DefaultMonetaryAmountFormat.parse(DefaultMonetaryAmountFormat.java:190)
at test.main(test.java:27)
```

This happens if provided locale is not associated with one of $, € or £. For instance this code will work for `Locale.US`, but will crash for `Locale.CHINA` as well as with `new Locale("pl", "PL")`. So this is not only problem with custom defined `Locale` but those statically predefined as well.

I have dug a little into the internal package and found `org.javamoney.moneta.internal.format.CurrencyToken.parse(CurrencyToken.java:196)`, which looks like:

```
case SYMBOL:
    if (token.startsWith("$")) {
        cur = Monetary.getCurrency("USD");
        context.consume("$");
    } else if (token.startsWith("€")) {
        cur = Monetary.getCurrency("EUR");
        context.consume("€");
    } else if (token.startsWith("£")) {
        cur = Monetary.getCurrency("GBP");
        context.consume("£");
    } else {
        cur = Monetary.getCurrency(token);
        context.consume(token);
    }
    context.setParsedCurrency(cur);
    break;
```

Is there any way to make my code above work for currencies other than $, € or £?

---

I have try few more things for instance provided Locale.CANADA they also have $ as currency symbol so it execute without failure but returns wrong data

```
    Locale LANG = Locale.CANADA;

    final MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
            AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(LANG)
                    .set(CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
                    .set("pattern", "#,##0.00### ¤")
                    .build()
    );
    final String formatted = format.format(Money.of(new BigDecimal("1234.56"), Monetary.getCurrency(LANG)));

    System.out.println(formatted);

    System.out.println(format.parse(formatted).getCurrency().getCurrencyCode());
```

last line return `USD` instead of `CAD` which is what this if-else does for $. I think it also wrongly assumes that symbol - currency is one to one mapping.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on a solution, issues raised https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/issues/149.

Expect Moneta patches for this and other issues soon.

Werner