# How to format MonetaryAmount with currency symbol?

Tags: java, jsr354

*Edit:* This question is intended to be for formatting within the context of JSR-354. An alternative would be to use `java.util.CurrencyFormat`. But I want to know how to do it using `MonetaryAmountFormat`.

**How do you format a `MonetaryAmount` using the currency symbol within the context of JSR-354 `MonetaryAmountFormat`?**

I tried to use `MonetaryAmountFormat` as demonstrated below from two different examples I found on the web. Neither approach worked properly so I pushed my example test cases to [github](https://github.com/axiopisty/stackoverflow/blob/master/jsr354/src/test/java/com/github/axiopisty/stackoverflow/jsr354/TestMonetaryAmountFormat.java) in case you would like to clone and see the full details but here is the test:

*pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
  <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

*TestMonetaryAmountFormat.java*

```
package com.github.axiopisty.stackoverflow.jsr354;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.money.CurrencyUnit;
import javax.money.Monetary;
import javax.money.MonetaryAmount;
import javax.money.format.AmountFormatQueryBuilder;
import javax.money.format.MonetaryAmountFormat;
import javax.money.format.MonetaryFormats;
import org.javamoney.moneta.Money;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestMonetaryAmountFormat {

  private final String EXPECTED = "$12.99";

  private final CurrencyUnit USD = Monetary.getCurrency("USD");
  private final MonetaryAmount AMOUNT = Money.of(new BigDecimal("12.99"), USD);

  /**
   * See: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.money.format.MonetaryAmountFormat
   */
  @Test
  public void testFormatWithCurrencySymbol_1() {
    MonetaryAmountFormat maf = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
      AmountFormatQueryBuilder
        .of(Locale.US)
        .setFormatName("SYMBOL")
        .build()
    );
    String actual = maf.format(AMOUNT);
    assertEquals(EXPECTED, actual);
    /**
     * The previous assert statement results in the following:
     *
     * javax.money.MonetaryException: No MonetaryAmountFormat for AmountFormatQuery AmountFormatQuery (
     * {Query.formatName=SYMBOL, java.util.Locale=en_US})
     * at javax.money.spi.MonetaryFormatsSingletonSpi.getAmountFormat(MonetaryFormatsSingletonSpi.java:71)
     * at javax.money.format.MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(MonetaryFormats.java:110)
     * at com.github.axiopisty.stackoverflow.jsr354.TestMonetaryAmountFormat.testFormatWithCurrencySymbol_1(TestMonetaryAmountFormat.java:26)
     * ...
     **/
  }

  /**
   * See: https://github.com/JavaMoney/javamoney-examples/issues/25
   */
  @Test
  public void testFormatWithCurrencySymbol_2() {
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    MonetaryAmountFormat maf = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
      AmountFormatQueryBuilder
        .of(Locale.US)
        .set(symbols)
        .build()
    );
    String actual = maf.format(AMOUNT);

    assertEquals(EXPECTED, actual);
    /**
     * The previous assert statement results in the following:
     *
     * org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
     * Expected :$12.99
     * Actual   :USD12.99
     */
  }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you use java.util.CurrencyFormat?

Comment: I can, but this question is intended within the bounds of JSR354 and it's formatting capabilities.

Comment: RTFM.  see section "4.4. Money and Currency Formatting API" of the final spec.  It includes code examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer just after asking the question. I updated the github project to contain the solution.

```
  /**
   * See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40244526/328275
   */
  @Test
  public void test3() {
    final MonetaryAmountFormat format = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(
      AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.US)
        .set(CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
        .build()
    );
    final String actual = format.format(AMOUNT);
    assertEquals(EXPECTED, actual);
  }
```

Comment: How to get only Symbol ?